# Gitlab API - How to fetch most recent commit from multiple repositories available in the same gitlab group?

Tags: gitlab

We just wanted to check is there any way to find most recent commit from multiple repositories available in the same git lab group using git-lab api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [commits API to list commits](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#list-repository-commits). By default, commits are shown in reverse-chronological order, so the most recent commit will be the first result in the response.

You can also use the [group list projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#list-a-groups-projects) if needed to find all the projects in a group.

Comment: I think commits API to list commits is for project specific. we need to get commits of all the projects present in the same gitlab group